# How to enable unlimited course retake for limited time in LearnPress?

Tags: plugins

Couple of questions about LearnPress:

1. How to allow unlimited retake of a course? Currently I can allow only specific number of retakes.
2. Can you limit course to be accessible for certain time? Like 2 months from date of purchase.

Thank you!

Comment: Specific plugin support is out of scope for WPSE. You'd be better suited directing this question to LearnPress support.